# Matlab, plotyy, datetime, and DatetimeTickFormat

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab R2015a, and would like to control the `DatetimeTickFormat` when plotting with the `plotyy` function. However, `plotyy` does not take that argument, in contrast to the regular `plot` function.

How can I access and set the `DatetimeTickFormat` via a handle or command, after plotting with `plotyy`?

```
x_datenum = linspace(1,2,10);
t_datetime = datetime(x_datenum,'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');

figure
% WORKS, BUT GIVES NO CONTROL OVER THE 'DatetimeTickFormat'
[hAxPlotyy,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(t_datetime,1:10,t_datetime,2:11);

% DOES NOT WORK. HOW DO I SET A SPECIFIC 'DatetimeTickFormat' AFTERWARDS?
[hAxPlotyy,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(hAx,t_datetime,1:10,t_datetime,2:11,'DatetimeTickFormat','HH:mm:ss');
```

Thank you.

Comment: does `hAxPlotyy.DatetimeTickFormat` work? what about `gca.DatetimeTickFormat`?

Comment: None of those work, but thanks. I also tried `hAxPlotyy.XTickFormat` and `hAxPlotyy.TickFormat`. I have been looking at all the properties for hAxPlotyy in the Inspector window, but I have yet to find a property that seems to work for this issue.
EDIT: Actually there are no `XTickFormat` or `TickFormat` properties for my hAxPlotyy handle object, from what I see in the Inspector, but I simply tried those before looking at the Inspector.

Comment: Its weird because if you change the font of the axes, sometimes, the format changes. I got something like `20072015` instead of `20-jun-2015` and so on....

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help in this situation (still booting up my machine) but I generally try to avoid `plotyy` due to how fussy it's been for me historically. I've moved to just stacking axes and avoiding it altogether (one example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655347/non-homogenous-grouped-data-in-matlab-plotyy/30655776#30655776)).

Comment: Stepping through `plot` in the debugger it doesn't seem like `DatetimeTickFormat` is actually a property of the axes or plot, but instead a different version of `plot` is called that utilizes the internal `matlab.internal.datetime.makeTimePlot` function.

Comment: ...and one level deeper the axes ticks seem to be handled by another internal function, `matlab.internal.datetime.TimeAxisListenersManager` but it's p code so I can't get into it.

Comment: Alright. Thanks @excaza for digging this much into it! I'll take a look at your "stacking axes" method, mentioned in your comments above.
Should anyone come up with a method that works for controlling `DatetimeTickFormat`with `plotyy` I'd still appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like I went a bit too far down the `plot` rabbit hole without checking for a dedicated function first. Oops...

You can use [`datetime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) after your `plotyy` call to modify the ticks:

```
x_datenum = linspace(1,2,10);
t_datetime = datetime(x_datenum,'ConvertFrom', 'datenum');

[hAxPlotyy,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(t_datetime,1:10,t_datetime,2:11);
datetick(hAxPlotyy(1), 'x', 'HH:mm:ss');
```

Since `hAxPlotyy` returns a `1x2` array of axes objects and `datetime` apparently doesn't work on arrays of axes objects, I selected the primary axes object to modify.

[image: Modified X-axis ticks]

Comment: Thanks @excaza for your solution! BTW, I think you meant `datetick`, when you wrote `datetime`, in "_You can use datetime after your plotyy call_". I do have one gripe with `datetick`, which is that having used it, the a-axis tick marks will not auto update when using the zoom tool. But there are [workarounds](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95034-why-does-datetick-not-regenerate-tick-marks-on-the-axes-when-using-the-zoom-function-in-matlab)

Comment: @ctp fixed, thanks. The zoom issue stems from how the tick labels are implemented for timeseries plots, as I was speaking to above in the comments. Because they are generated during the `plot` or `datetick` calls and are not a property of the axis, MATLAB does not know to update them once the plot is manipulated. The FEX submission in the linked MATLAB Central post is a clever mod to the `zoom` and `pan` functionality.

Comment: I Just wanted to add some feedback on your axes stacking method, as you (@excaza) describe [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30655347/non-homogenous-grouped-data-in-matlab-plotyy/30655776#30655776). It really works wonders and it allows me to work with the `DatetimeTickFormat` as I want!! And then I simply remove ticklabels from x-axis 2, so I don't get "overprint", like so:
`h.ax2.XTickLabel = [];` Thanks again!