# Matlab, XLimMode and DurationTickFormat

Tags: matlab

Using Matlab R2015a, I have set the `XLim` property on the axes I'm plotting to, to manually control the x-axis range and make the plot curves fit the width of the axis nicely.

I set `XLim` before using the plot command, but have found that `XLimMode` seems to be reset to `'auto'` when using `DurationTickFormat` or `DatetimeTickFormat` arguments with the plot command.

I can set `XLim` once again after plotting, but I'd rather that Matlab simply respected the x-limits when plotting, since it takes additional time subsequently, to rearrange a number of detailed curves to fit the x-limits.

Any tips on how to force `plot` to respect `XLim` in conjunction with `DurationTickFormat` or `DatetimeTickFormat` would be much appreciated.

Example code to illustrate the issue:

```
clear;

%% TEST 1 - NO DURATION TICK FORMAT
fprintf('TEST 1:\n');
xData = 0:0.1:2*pi;
yData = sin(xData);

hFig1 = figure;
hAx1 = axes('Parent',hFig1);
fprintf('XLimMode BEFORE setting xlim: %s\n', hAx1.XLimMode);
hAx1.XLim = [0 2*pi];
hold(hAx1,'on');
fprintf('XLimMode AFTER setting xlim: %s\n', hAx1.XLimMode);
plot(hAx1, xData, yData);
fprintf('XLimMode AFTER PLOT command: %s\n', hAx1.XLimMode);


%% TEST 2 - DURATION TICK FORMAT
fprintf('\nTEST 2:\n');
xDuration = days(xData);

hFig2 = figure;
hAx2 = axes('Parent',hFig2);
fprintf('XLimMode BEFORE setting xlim: %s\n', hAx2.XLimMode);
hAx2.XLim = [datenum(days(0)) datenum(days(2*pi))];
hold(hAx2,'on');
fprintf('XLimMode AFTER setting xlim: %s\n', hAx2.XLimMode);
plot(hAx2, xDuration, yData, 'DurationTickFormat','hh:mm:ss');
fprintf('XLimMode AFTER PLOT command: %s\n', hAx2.XLimMode);
```

Console output:

```
TEST 1:
XLimMode BEFORE setting xlim: auto
XLimMode AFTER setting xlim: manual
XLimMode AFTER PLOT command: manual

TEST 2:
XLimMode BEFORE setting xlim: auto
XLimMode AFTER setting xlim: manual
XLimMode AFTER PLOT command: auto
```

Visual result:

[image: Test 1]

[image: Test 2]

Comment: I'll have to poke around and see for sure, but from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962979/matlab-plotyy-datetime-and-datetimetickformat/31964791#31964791) remember that the `Datetime` ticks are handled by a function external to the `plot` command and may modify the axes limits on its own.

Comment: Thanks @excaza , yes I see where (re my previous question) the trouble could be. Well, if your poking around leads to any tips for this issue, I'd appreciate it :)